# ControlTemplate in Xamarin.Forms is breaking command in listView in Content Page

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, controltemplate, eventtocommand

*Xamarin.Forms*

I'm working with **ControlTemplates** as described in [this article](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-page-templates/).

Creating the controlTemplate went without a hitch, as did applying it and even binding to it. The problem is that while most of the binding still works in my ContentPage, the **EventToCommand in my ListView has broken** (tapping no longer invokes the command).

Have you seen this before? Is this a known problem? Is there a fix?

Thanks!!
jesse

Answer (score 0):

I've established that when templates are used the **ItemSelected event never fires**.  I will file a bug report.